# How to access to a Object array in parse config?

Tags: android, parse-platform

In my Parse Config I have this parameter:

lastRatio   Object  {"ratio":10000,"time":300}

How can I access to it from android? I tried this so far but didn't work

```
ParseConfig.getInBackground(new ConfigCallback(){
                             public void done(ParseConfig config, ParseException e){
                                 Object ratio = config.get("lastRatio");
                                 Toast.makeText(RequestServiceActivity.this, "Ratio: "+ ratio, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

ratio is {"ratio":10000,"time":300} always, I only want to acces to "ratio":10000

Comment: lastRatio is object, not array

Comment: Ok but how can I acces to {"ratio" : 10000}

Comment: You are getting JSON back from ParseCloud, so you'll need to parse out the value you want

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 that help me ! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String ratio=config.getString("ratio");
```

by this you can access value of object ratio ="1000"